# On a regressed planet, two identical sisters take turns being the queen, while the other gets away and relaxes in disguise

Tags: story-identification

USA Paperback in English probably from the 1980s.

On a planet that has been out of touch with the rest of the rest of civilization for awhile (I believe it was regressed to middle ages level) an Envoy from another planet arrives and meets the queen's sister at a remote lodge. (There, a stable hand/gardener/cleaner seems annoyed with the sister because she spends her time talking with the Envoy and does not even notice him.) Then they journey to the kingdom to meet the Queen.

Along the way the sister gets a pretty bad cut on her arm (hand? leg?) that will needs stitches to heal, and is going to leave a nasty scar. But the Envoy uses a medical device to help heal it. There is a scar but it is much less than it would have been.

Shortly after arriving at the kingdom the Envoy catches the Queen using the same medical device to give herself the same matching scar as her sister. It turns out the two sisters are *identical twins*, but the sister who is *not* the queen, using makeup, wigs, and clothing, dresses much differently so they do *not* look alike.

They have been swapping out every few weeks or months so that while one is Queen (dealing with the stress of ruling) the other can go out, relax, and enjoy life and unwind from all the stress. (The young man at the lodge in the beginning had been flirted with by the other sister. Which is why he was upset, when the second one was not continuing the affection)

Eventually something serious happens to the sister and she is seriously injured. She is going to need major lifesaving medical treatment to survive which cant be done on the planet. The Envoy is going to need to take her off planet to save her life. It will be a voyage of a year or more before they can return. And the current Queen in addition to being worried for her sister is stressing about having to be the Queen by herself for probably years.